# SQL Selecting Maximum Based on Minor-Major scheme

Tags: t-sql, max

I am trying to create a query that will select a DISTINCT line, select using a revision Minor / Major scheme.  Below is an example table:

```
Serial Number | RevMajor | RevMinor
-----------------------------------
AQ155         |    1     |    1
AQ155         |    1     |    2  
AQ155         |    1     |    1
AQ155         |    1     |    7    
AQ155         |    2     |    1  <---------
JR2709        |    1     |    7
JR2709        |    2     |    2  <---------
```

How can I write a query in T-SQL 2008 that will select only the two highlighted lines, the "Newest Revision"?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could

```
select * from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by [Serial Number] order by RevMajor desc, RevMinor desc) VersionRank
    from table
) T
where VersionRank = 1
```

Comment: Thanks this one is useful because it allows me to select additional columns if I wanted to, without having to worry about GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

```
select [serial number], revmajor, revminor
from table1
where revMajor = (select max(revmajor) from table1)
```

another way to do this could be:

```
select [serial number], revmajor, revminor
from table1 a
inner join ( select max(revMajor) from table1 ) b on a.revmajor = b.revmajor
```

Another way **if you know there are only 2 rows**:

```
    select top 2 [serial number], revmajor, revminor
    from table1 a
    order by revmajor desc, revminor desc
```